# Will linking my computer to a different account delete my first account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a level 73 on my iPod and the same account on my computer. If I link the account on my computer to another account, will it erase the one on my iPod? I don't think I will lose all progress, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you link your computer to a different account it will not erase the progress you have on your iPod.